# Array push don't working properly

Tags: php

I'm using `array_push` to add elements to the array in a specific `key` position, check my code:

```
foreach($query as $key)
{
    $appointment['id_services'] = array_push($appointment,$key['id_services']);
}

print_r($appointment['id_services']);
```

Now `$query` contains in my case two array, I iterate through `$query` variable and take the two `id_services` the values returned is: `14` and `13`. Anyway, when I print the `appointment['id_services]` array index I get: `16`, but why? It should create another array in `appointment['id_services]` with this structure:

```
[0] => 14
[1] => 13
```

I need to push the element not overwrite it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is not the correct way to use array push. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Please post what `$appointment` contains before the loop and what you want it to look like after the loop.

Comment: So I guess that I must create another array, push the services, and after insert in the specific key of appointment array the value of whole service array?

Comment: Try changing `$appointment['id_services'] = array_push($appointment,$key['id_services']);` to `array_push($appointment['id_services'],$key['id_services']);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to assign it to anything. It's just a function call:

```
<?php
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);
?>
```

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) for more info..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `[]` operator to append (push) to arrays. Simply do this:

```
foreach ( $query as $key )
    $appointment['id_services'][] = $key['id_services'];

print_r( $appointment['id_services'] );
```

This will push the value of `$key['id_services']` to the `$appointment['id_services']` array.

Alternatively, using [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) (which returns the new size of the array):

```
foreach ( $query as $key )
    array_push( $appointment['id_services'], $key['id_services'] );
```